# Why Visual Studio is modifying target names when open CMake projects?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I have some questions about Visual Studio (not visual studio code)

I'm writing a `launch.vs.json` but meet with 2 problems:

- In `CMakeLists.txt`, I added targets without any suffix, for example, `test_runner`, but when I open this folder with VS, the Startup Item pulldown menu shows `test_runner (C:\\.xxxxxx)`, i.e. it appends a directory path behind the real target name, so in `launch.vs.json`, I have to append it as well. How to prevent vs from doing this? Can I customize this name in VS?
- I have an env variable `ref_version` set by `set` command in cmake, the debug dll path is related to this variable. For examplem, if I set `ref_version` to 3, my debugging process should be run under `.\\ver3\\bin`. So when I modify `ref_version`, I have to switch to another Startup Item configurated in `launch.vs.json`. As since the possible value of this variable is so many, I have to write a long json. So how can I reuse the variable name in `CMakeLists.txt` in `launch.vs.json`? I tried `${env.ref_version}` but it won't evaluate.